# screen orientation in Live Wallpaper

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, screen-orientation, live-wallpaper

I have  created a live wallpaper It is working fine in portrait mode but when i put the phone in Landscape mode the view does not appear properly.Now what i want to do is "To fix the screen orientation in portrait mode". How can i do this for a live wallpaper?
I tried to rotate the bitmap and the canvas but it is appear not as good. Is there any tutorial on rotating the canvas and bitmap? Please suggest and please advice me for my problem. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have also a problem when changing the screen orientation. My wallpaper redraws just once per minute, so I have to trigger a redraw, when the orientation is changed. Do you have an idea which event is called when the orientation is changed?

Comment: But back to your question: In my case I just work with canvas to draw my stuff. And I don't have to do anything special to draw in landscape mode. When the phone is in portrait mode canvas.getWidth() is the width of my phone, when the phone is in landscape mode canvas.getWidth() is the height of my phone. So I don't have to turn it around or something like this...

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at my code:

```
    public class PonyWallpaper extends AnimationWallpaper {
        /*some code here*/
        class PonyEngine extends AnimationEngine {
        /*some code here as well*/
            @Override
            public void onSurfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
                    int width, int height) {
                Log.v("orientation changed", "w: "+width + " h: " + height + " width desired: " + this.getDesiredMinimumWidth() + " height desired: " + this.getDesiredMinimumHeight());
```

with AnimationEngine declared as

```
protected abstract class AnimationEngine extends android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService.Engine
```

The output when switching to portrait from landscape:

> orientation changed(352): w: 800 h: 480 width desired: 960 height
>   desired: 800

The output when switching to landscape from portrait:

> orientation changed(352): w: 480 h: 800 width desired: 960 height
>   desired: 800

As you can see, method onSurfaceChanged of the android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService.Engine class is called every time an orientation gets changed.

From what i've noticed,

> this.getDesiredMinimumWidth()

and

> this.getDesiredMinimumHeight()

don't change and are maximum possible values of width and height.

My solution was:

- to pass width, desired width, height and desired height to a method of my drawer object;
- to call drawObject() - like methods with a coordinates ranging from 0.0 to 1.0;
- to scale those values inside drawer object to logical coordinates described by desired width and desired height;
- to set an offset of a real x coordinates judging by xPixelOffset passed by

> onOffsetsChanged

method of

> android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService.Engine

- to set an offeset of a real y coordinates judging by difference of a real height and desired height.

I hope that will help!

Comment: I've just found two preinstalled live wallpapers with fixed portrait orientation in my new Sony Xperia TX. The screen also is fixed in the portrait mode if you use one of those live wallpapers. So, perhaps, it's some way to set it by option...